# Force window to blink when a particular event occurs in C# / UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am using C# / UWP to make an application. In that application, I want to blink the window if a particular event occurs so that user of that application knows that something happened. How can I get this in my C# UWP application?

Like in Yahoo Messenger, if you get a message then the message window blinks to get your focus, I want to use that effect in my application.

Comment: why can't try notifications instead !
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/notifications/notificationsoverview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

​Currently, there seems no api can blink your app's icon in Taskbar. If you want to achieve some eye-catching effects, you can use notification or make notification badges appear on your app's taskbar icon, but it is a static effect without animation. For more details, you can refer to this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/badges

```
private void updateBadgeGlyph()
 {​
     string badgeGlyphValue = "attention";​
 ​
     XmlDocument badgeXml = ​
         BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeGlyph);​
 ​
     Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement badgeElement = ​
         badgeXml.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement;​
     badgeElement.SetAttribute("value", badgeGlyphValue);​
 ​
     BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(badgeXml);​
 ​
     BadgeUpdater badgeUpdater = ​
         BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication();​
 ​
     badgeUpdater.Update(badge);​
 ​
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean. But UWP apps are different from Win32 apps, you cannot control the focus of the `Window`.

I mean, if the current application does not get focus (such as minimized), then the operation on the current `ApplicationView` is invalid.

But compared to the window blinking, UWP's information application has a better way of prompting, such as `ToastNotification`, which is the recommended practice.

If you want to learn more about `ToastNotification`, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-ux-guidance)

Best regards.